# Small Launcher Application

Tags: c#

I have just somewhat completed a program, and was wondering what I could do to improve readability, and design as some functions seems to be rather large and an eye-sore.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using WoWLauncher.Properties;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;

namespace WoWLauncher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                DragMove();
        }

        private void Minimize_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Exit_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private async void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IProgress<int> progressPercent = new Progress<int>(percent =>
            {
                if (progressBar.IsIndeterminate)
                    progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                progressBar.Value = percent;
            });
            IProgress<string> progressText = new Progress<string>(text => updateLabel.Content = text);
            windowTitle.Content = Settings.Default.ServerTitle;

            news.Text = await GetNews(progressText);
            await GetWoWDirectory();
            await CheckUpdates(progressPercent, progressText);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetNews(IProgress<string> updateText)
        {
            try
            {
                updateText.Report("Fetching news.");
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Settings.Default.NewsUrl);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                return "Failed to fetch news";
            }
        }

        private static async Task GetWoWDirectory()
        {   
            var directory = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FindWoWDirectory());
            if (directory == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find WoW Directory. Please choose.");
                var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    directory = dialog.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
            Settings.Default.WoWFolder = directory;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void Register_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            Process.Start(Settings.Default.RegisterUrl);
        }

        private void SetRealmlist_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            SetRealmlist();
        }

        private void Launch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            CheckRealmlist();
            Process.Start(Path.Combine(FindWoWDirectory(), "Wow.exe"));
        }

        private async Task CheckUpdates(IProgress<int> progressPercentage, IProgress<string> progressText)
        {
            progressText.Report("Checking for updates...");
            var data = Path.Combine(FindWoWDirectory(), "Data");
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                var updates = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Settings.Default.UpdateUrl);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(updates) || !updates.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    progressPercentage.Report(100);
                    progressText.Report("No updates found");
                    launch.Content = "Launch";
                    launch.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    var list = new List<string>(Regex.Split(updates, Environment.NewLine));
                    foreach (var url in list)
                    {
                        var fileName = url.Split('/').Last();
                        var fileSize = CheckSize(url);
                        var localFileName = Path.Combine(data, fileName);
                        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFileName);
                        if (fileInfo.Exists)
                        {
                            if (fileInfo.Length == fileSize)
                                continue;
                            fileInfo.MoveTo(fileInfo.FullName + ".bak");
                        }

                        progressText.Report($"Downloading file {fileName}");
                        await DownloadFile(url, fileInfo.FullName, progressPercentage);
                    }
                    progressPercentage.Report(100);
                    progressText.Report("Client up to date");
                    launch.Content = "Launch";
                    launch.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ReceiveFailure)
                {
                    progressText.Report("Failed to check for updates");
                    progressPercentage.Report(100);
                    launch.Content = "Launch";
                    launch.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string path, IProgress<int> progress = null)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    progress?.Report(e.ProgressPercentage);
                };

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, path);
            }
        }

        private static long CheckSize(string url)
        {
            var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());
            return resp.ContentLength;
        }

        private static string FindWoWDirectory()
        {
            if (Settings.Default.WoWFolder != string.Empty)
                return Settings.Default.WoWFolder;

            var possibleDirectories = new[]
            {
                @"{0}World of Warcraft\",
                @"{0}Program Files\World of Warcraft\",
                @"{0}Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"
            };
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (var wowPath in drives
                .SelectMany(drive => possibleDirectories.Select(directory => string.Format(directory, drive.Name))
                .Where(Directory.Exists)
                .Select(CheckVersion)))
            {
                return wowPath;
            }

            return drives.Select(drive => CheckVersion(drive.Name)).FirstOrDefault(wowPath => wowPath != null);
        }

        private static string CheckVersion(string wowPath)
        {
            var wowExes = Directory.GetFiles(wowPath, "Wow.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            return (from wowExe in wowExes
                    let versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(wowExe)
                    where versionInfo.FileVersion.Replace(", ", ".") == Settings.Default.Patch
                    select new FileInfo(wowExe).DirectoryName).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private static string GetLocaleFolder()
        {
            var wowDirectory = FindWoWDirectory();
            var realmlists = new[]
            {
                "GB",
                "US"
            };

            return (from realmlist in realmlists
                    select Path.Combine(wowDirectory, $@"Data\en{realmlist}\") 
                    into folder where Directory.Exists(folder)
                    select folder).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private static string GetRealmlist()
        {
            return Path.Combine(GetLocaleFolder(), "realmlist.wtf");
        }

        private static void SetRealmlist()
        {
            var file = GetRealmlist();
            if (File.Exists(file))
                File.Copy(file, file + ".bak", true);
            File.WriteAllText(file, Settings.Default.Realmlist);
        }

        private static void CheckRealmlist()
        {
            var file = GetRealmlist();
            var contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
            if (contents != Settings.Default.Realmlist)
                SetRealmlist();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I get a number of errors when I put it into Visual Studio.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am sure that it works. The Settings file is not included and you need to be on .NET Framework 4.5 / 4.6 (not sure which).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
     DragMove();
```

[ln 30-31] Style choice: I recommend using `{}` around conditionals, even if they're only one line - because if you update them and make them more than one line and *forget* to add the brackets... exceptions.

Also, your indents are off here. Indent the first line of the snippet above by one more space.

---

```
private static async Task<string> GetNews(IProgress<string> updateText)
{
    try
    {
        updateText.Report("Fetching news.");
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Settings.Default.NewsUrl);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return "Failed to fetch news";
    }
}
```

[ln 60] Single responsibility: if `GetNews`'s purpose is to get news, it shouldn't also be dealing with notifying the user if there is none.

Make this method return `null` if there is no news to be had because of the `WebException`, and do the check in the UI code [ln 55]:

```
var news = await GetNews(progressText);
news.Text = news == null ? "Failed to fetch news" : news;
```

---

```
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

[ln 81] You've already included `System.Windows.Forms` - no need to have the entire name here.

---

```
Realmlist
```

[multiple] As mentioned in other answers: rename `Realmlist` to `RealmList` or `Realms`.

---

```
private static string FindWoWDirectory()
{
    if (Settings.Default.WoWFolder != string.Empty)
```

[ln 179] Folder !== Directory. Be consistent throughout: if this is a setting that a user needs to understand (hence why you used Folder instead of Directory), convert it to Directory code-side.

---

```
var realmlists = new[]
{
    "GB",
    "US"
};
```

[ln 215] `realmlists`? Seems like one list to me. Rename it; again, consider the point above that it should be `realms`.

---

More in general, this class is doing too much. This is the code-behind for `MainWindow`, it seems, which should be an effector class (handling what the user *sees*). Make another class containing the helper methods like `GetNews`, `GetWoWDirectory`, etc., for the business layer, and refer to it from `MainWindow`.

Comment: Very nice. The portion on GetNews returning null is a much better idea than what I had. The realmlist is a property of the WoW game client that's the location of the realmlist.

Answer (score 5):

It seems a bit odd to me that you suddenly use `MessageBox.Show("Cannot find WoW Directory. Please choose.");`, whereas in other places you update `updateLabel`.

---

`Realmlist` is a compound word, so it should be `RealmList`. Actually, scrap that, it should be `Realms` because you should avoid using the name of the type in the name of the property or field.

---

I'm not a big fan of some of your names. For instance: `progressText` doesn't really convey what it is. (Also please be consistent: in one place you name this `updateText`.)

---

Watch out for inconsistent naming: `FindWoWDirectory` vs `WoWFolder`, for instance.

---

You have a `using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top, yet you still specify the full namespace in the code: `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`.

---

Even though this isn't that long (250 lines), I still feel that there's a lot of code in this class that belongs in a dedicated class, e.g. the update check, retrieval of the WoW directory,...

[Web Forms MVP](https://github.com/webformsmvp/webformsmvp) is probably overkill for this kind of project (since I doubt there will be much functionality to be added in the future), but I'd still try to limit the code in this `MainWindow` class to UI-related code, and move all other code to smaller dedicated classes.